# direct mutation working but the setState not updating, what should i use?

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to update my state in react js . direct state mutation is updating the state but set State not working , Why ?

this updates

```
 var arrNew = [{ name: "hasan ", age: 645 }, { name: "hasan ", age: 64 }, { name: "hasan ", age: 6} ]; 

    console.log("old state ----> ", this.state.arr)

    this.state.arr = arrNew ;

    console.log("new state ----> ",this.state.arr)
```

this is not doing anything ... ?

```
this.setState({
  arr: [...this.state.arr, arrNew]
})
```

this is my full code .....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';



class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){

    super(props);

    this.state = { arr : [] , show : false }
  }

  handleChange = ()  => {


    var arrNew = [{ name: "hasan ", age: 645 }, { name: "hasan ", age: 64 }, { name: "hasan ", age: 6} ]; 

    console.log("old state ----> ", this.state.arr)

    this.setState({
      arr: [...this.state.arr, arrNew],
      show: true,
    })

    console.log("new state ----> ",this.state.arr)

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

      <button onClick= { this.handleChange } > Get Data </button>

      <div id= "show">
      { 
            this.state.show ? ( this.state.arr.map( data => {
              <ul>
                <li> data.name </li>
                <li> data.age </li>
              </ul>
            })) : null
      }

      </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What's the output of `this.setState({ arr: [...this.state.arr, arrNew]}, () => console.log(this.state.arr));`?

Comment: old state ---->  []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
App.js:30 new state ---->  []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: It's better to use a helper like ```immutability-helper``` for this situation, because your array has object.
```{$push: array}``` is the solution.

sources: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html
https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper

Comment: Can you show the component  code where you are updating your state using `this.setState` ?

Comment: should not you spread the items of arrNew array when creating the new arr ?

Comment: move your '  console.log("new state ----> ",this.state.arr)' out of `handleChange` and put inside render (before return ()) and then tell me what are you getting in `console.log`

Comment: @shahin-hasan, can you please test again my following Answer.

Comment: @salman.zare has a valid answer as well using a different approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the callback you are passing to your map method ( since that function is returning undefined because you are using curly brackets)and spread the items of arrNew and it works. Maybe your code is failing silently

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){

    super(props);

    this.state = { arr : [] , show : false }
  }

  handleChange = ()  => {


    var arrNew = [{ name: "hasan ", age: 645 }, { name: "hasan ", age: 64 }, { name: "hasan ", age: 6} ]; 

    //console.log("old state ----> ", this.state.arr)
    this.setState({
       arr: [...this.state.arr, ...arrNew],
      show : true
    })


    //console.log("new state ----> ",this.state.arr)

  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    const { arr, show } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">

      <button onClick= { this.handleChange } > Get Data </button>

      <div id="show">
      { 
         this.state.show ? (this.state.arr.map((data, i)=> (
            <ul key={i}>
             <li> {data.name} </li>
             <li> {data.age} </li>
            </ul>
          ))) : null
      }

      </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>, 
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

working [demo](https://jsbin.com/vinonuvuye/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: if you mean with ... to the spread operator, you can find information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

@shahin-hasan, you can use something like the following:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import update from 'immutability-helper';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {arr: []};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    debugger;
    var arrNew = [{name: "hasan ", age: 645}, {name: "hasan ", age: 64}, {name: "hasan ", age: 6}];
    const tmp = update(this.state.arr, {$push: arrNew});
    this.setState({
      arr: tmp
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="button" value={this.props.formName} onClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```